# prove that $a^2yz+b^2zx+c^2xy\leq 0$ for all real $x,y,x$ such that $x+y+z=0$

Tags: inequality

prove that $a^2yz+b^2zx+c^2xy\leq 0$ for all real $x,y,x$ such that $x+y+z=0$
  Given that $a,b,c$ are positive real numbers such that the sum of any two is greater than third.
 We have $x+y+z=0\implies x+y=-z\implies xz+yz=-z^2$
What will be the next?

Comment: This is incorrect without some restriction on $a,b,c$. For instance, $a=0, b=0, c=1$, $x=1,y=1$ and $z=-2$, gives us $$ a^2yz+b^2zx+c^2xy = 1 > 0$$

Comment: and what kind of numbers are $a,b,c$ ?

Comment: i think a condition is missing

Comment: $a,b,c$ are +ve reals with $a+b>c, b+c>a, c+a>b$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that $x+y+z=0$, we have two of them to be of different sign. Without loss of generality, let us assume $x$ and $y$ have different sign, i.e., $xy\leq0$.

We have $z=-(x+y)$ and hence
\begin{align}
a^2yz + b^2zx + c^2xy & = c^2xy - (x+y)(a^2y+b^2x)\\
& = xy(c^2-a^2 - b^2) - a^2x^2 - b^2y^2\\
& = xy(c^2-a^2-b^2+2ab) - (ax+by)^2\\
& = xy (c^2-(a-b)^2) - (ax+by)^2\\
& = xy(c+a-b)(c-a+b) - (ax+by)^2 \leq 0
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

We need to prove that $$-a^2y(x+y)-b^2x(x+y)+c^2xy\leq0$$ or
$$b^2x^2+(a^2+b^2-c^2)xy+a^2y^2\geq0$$
and since $b>0$, it's enough to prove that
$$(a^2+b^2-c^2)^2-4a^2b^2\leq0$$ or
$$(a+b+c)(a+b-c)(a+c-b)(b+c-a)\geq0$$
and we are done!